# Pywinauto - There are 2 elements that match criteria

Tags: python, powerbi, pywinauto, inspect.exe

this is my first post!
I would like to ask you how can i solve this problem. I am trying to automate publish in powerBI. I need to click on correct workspace. Right now i am trying with " My workspace" which is there only once.
[**Please check this image of PowerBI window**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWVau.png)

[This is screen from inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCwSs.png)

part of python code looks like this:

```
win = app.window(title_re = '.*Power BI Desktop')
win.Publish.click_input()
publish_dialog = win.child_window(auto_id = "KoPublishToGroupDialog")
publish_dialog.child_window(title = "My Workspace").click_input()
publish_dialog.Select.click()
```

Error msg looks like this

```
There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'title': 'My workspace', 'top_level_only': False, 'parent': <uia_element_info.UIAElementInfo - 'Publish to Power BI', WindowsForms10.Window.20008.app.0.3c73ab4_r6_ad1, 667196>, 'backend': 'uia'}
```

Can somebody explain me what is problem and how can i solve this?

[Additional info from inspect.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWn0S.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: You can choose which element to find: `child_window(title = "My Workspace", found_index=0)` Using `control_type` is also desired because it makes search faster.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose which element to find:

```
child_window(title="My Workspace", found_index=0) # or found_index=1
```

Using `control_type` is also desired because it makes search faster.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
dlg.Publish.click_input()
dlg.child_window(title="My workspace", control_type="DataItem", found_index=0).click_input()
dlg.Select.click()
```